# Console Keypress not working?

Tags: c#, console-application

So I'm making a console-based text game to learn more C# but I'm now stuck and have resorted to SO.

This might be an obvious answer but I require another pair of eyes to help me. I've checked the other questions on here and they don't seem to aid me.

In my `Main()`, I have the following:

```
        int age;

        Console.Write("Before entering the unknown, could you please confirm your age? ");
        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("");

        if (age < 18)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, you'll now be transferred to a non-explicit version.");
            Console.WriteLine("\n<Press any key to continue>");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Write("\nPlease wait...");
            for (int t = 5; t >= 0; t--)
            {
                Console.CursorLeft = 22;
                Console.Write("{0:00}" + " seconds remaining", t);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("\nTo proceed, please press any key...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            NonExplicit();
        }
```

Self explanatory. Once it hits the `NonExplicit()` method, the following is called:

```
        char yes = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        string name;

        Console.WriteLine("\nYou're awake? It's about time. Not old enough, eh? That sucks. \n\nListen, I really need your help. Would you be interested? Y / N");
        Console.ReadKey();

        if (yes == 'y' || yes == 'Y')
        {
            Console.Write("\nYou will?! Wow, That's fantastic. Right then, where shall I start? \nI know! How about telling me your name? ");
            name = Console.ReadKey().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("\nAhh yes, now you mention it, I certainly remember you, {0}!", name);   
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou don't want to help me? Oh, that's unfortunate... ");
        }
```

What seems to happen is that, when 'y' or 'Y' is pressed:

1) It requires enter to be hit to register the above.

2) It runs both the `if` & `else` `WriteLines`, which I assume is in conjunction with 1)?

How can I amend my code so that when 'y/Y' is pressed, it reads the correct criteria? Or how can I remove the need for Enter to be pressed to proceed?

Comment: `char yes = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;` and then a `WriteLine` followed by another `Console.ReadKey();`? Try moving the `char yes = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;` to replace the second `ReadKey()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used your code below, I tested it and it works.

I moved the `char yes = Console.ReadKey()` to below the `Console.WriteLine()`.
I changed the `name = Console.ReadKey()` to `Console.ReadLine()` because a name is more then 1 key.

```
        string name;
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou're awake? It's about time. Not old enough, eh? That sucks. \n\nListen, I really need your help. Would you be interested? Y / N");
        char yes = Console.ReadKey();

        if (yes == 'y' || yes == 'Y')
        {
            Console.Write("\nYou will?! Wow, That's fantastic. Right then, where shall I start? \nI know! How about telling me your name? ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\nAhh yes, now you mention it, I certainly remember you, {0}!", name);
            Console.ReadKey(); // I put this here so the program wouldn't exit
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou don't want to help me? Oh, that's unfortunate... ");
        }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Thank you for all the help, everyone.

Comment: No problem, thanks for providing a working code snippet :) that's why we could all help you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, after `Console.WriteLine("\nTo proceed, please press any key...");` you have `Console.ReadLine();` which expects you to enter a line in the console (not reading till you press enter) and then in your second method, you're trying to read the console again (but this time for a single key).

Wouldn't it help if you remove the first `Console.ReadLine()` ?

And then you are trying to get the yes/no answer before asking your question (and before doing another ReadKey.

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = Console.ReadLine();
if (result.ToUpper().Equals("Y"))
  {
     //any thing
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char yes = Console.ReadKey(); // No need for .KeyChar
```

> int age;
>
> Console.Write("Before entering the unknown, could you please confirm your age? ");
>   age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
>   Console.WriteLine("");

could be

```
int age = -1
Console.WriteLine("Before entering the unknown, could you please confirm your age? ");
while (age == -1)
{
    if !(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid age");
    }
}
```

> name = Console.ReadKey().ToString();

should be

```
name = Console.ReadLine();
```

> if (yes == 'y' || yes == 'Y')

could be

```
if (yes.ToUpper() == "Y")
```